# TikZ text not nicely vertically aligned

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I use lines and text to clarify a TikZ figure. However if I use the same y-coordinate (in tthe example below 3) and offset (in this case 'above'), the text looks messy.

**How can I get the alignment right of different nodes with the same (y) coordinates?**

This:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[color=red](0,3)--(11,3); 
\draw (0.5,2.5)--(0.5,3) node[above] {For Example:};
\draw (3,2.5)--(2.5,3) node[above] {this looks};
\draw (5,2.5)--(5.5,3) node[above] {not nice vertically aligned};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in Miktex/TexLive PDFLatex into:

[image: This looks not nice]

Comment: Welcome! This happens because some nodes have descenders in their texts while others do not. Use a `\strut` in your node texts or add suitable values of `text height` and `text depth` to the node options (best done with a style).

Answer (score 6):

You can also `anchor` nodes on its `baseline`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={above=2mm, anchor=base}]
\draw[color=red](0,3)--(11,3); 
\draw (0.5,2.5)--(0.5,3) node {For Example:};
\draw (3,2.5)--(2.5,3) node {this looks};
\draw (5,2.5)--(5.5,3) node {not nice vertically aligned};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Paul, this did the trick:

```
\draw (0.5,2.5)--(0.5,3) node[above] {\strut For Example:};
\draw (3,2.5)--(2.5,3) node[above] {\strut this looks};
\draw (5,2.5)--(5.5,3) node[above] {\strut not nice vertically aligned};
```