# How to align single character nodes at equivalent positions in side-by-side tikz pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption, alignment, tikz-positioning

I would like to use `tikz` in combination with `graphicx` and `subcaption` to achieve automatically labeled subfigures that I can refer to in text. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
    \phantomcaption{}\label{thisfig}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rectangle, inner sep=0] (image) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
      \node[below right = 0cm and 0cm] (label) at (image.north west) {\textbf{\subref{thisfig}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
    \phantomcaption{}\label{thatfig}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rectangle, inner sep=0] (image) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
      \node[below right = 0cm and 0cm] (label) at (image.north west) {\textbf{\subref{thatfig}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: MWE output with misaligned labels]

If you look closely, you will notice that the labels `a` and `b` are vertically misaligned. The top ends of the characters are aligned, resulting in the `b` to be visually too low. How can I align the labels like in regular text `a   b`, without breaking the structure of two subcaptions with one image each?

Comment: Try adding `anchor=base` to the options of the node with the label, or add a `\strut` in the node text (i.e. `{\strut\textbf{\subref..`. Sort of same basic problem as for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235086/ I think.

Comment: `anchor=base` has no effect for me, but `\strut` seems to fix my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: positioning options like `below right` also set the anchor, so you need to do `below right=..., anchor=...` in that order. Try e.g. `\node[below=2.5ex, anchor=base west] ...`